# Get div's margin value?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to read a div's margins with JavaScript if those margins are set in `external css` file. 
So far I am able to read div's margin data when it is written as an inline style (not in CSS file but inside HTML):

```
(function() {
  var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
  var move = document.getElementById('box');

  banner.onclick = function() {

    alert(move.style.marginLeft);

  };
})();
```

Here is JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/b0kaLk1f/

It works well but just remove  `style="margin-left: 500px"` and it will stop working.  I'd like to read CSS data from `style.css` file rather than from inline styles.

Comment: [__Window.getComputedStyle()__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @TJ - i have crrected all major typos

Comment: @trazaburo - I have to read margins to animate divs

Comment: You still have a typo in the question title.

Comment: Why do you need to know the margins to animate divs? Is this possibly something that `box-sizing` could help with? Thinking you need to use `getComputedStyle` to access style information usually indicates that your design is suboptimal. There are almost always better ways.

Comment: @Rossitten: I've finished the job for you. Thanks for making the effort, though.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Crowder..sorry for the mess.

Comment: @torazaburo: https://jsfiddle.net/b0kaLk1f/1/ 
This is a rough version of what I am working on. Honestly - I got a request to create an extendable HTML5 banner....is there a better way to dig into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method gives the values of all the CSS properties of an element after applying the active `stylesheets` and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.

```js
(function() {
  var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
  var move = document.getElementById('box');
  banner.onclick = function() {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(move, null);
    alert(style.marginLeft);
  };
})();
```

```css
#box {
  margin-left: 500px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background: #af0000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
#banner {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an X/Y problem, so it would be better to ask what the "X" is first.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are trying to maintain state in the form of style properties, which is not a good idea. You will have to retrieve them and set them. Instead, use a class to move the extended banner back and forth. The code is shorter and simpler:

```
banner.onclick = function () {
  ext.classList.toggle('hide_extended_banner');
};
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/b0kaLk1f/2/.

Comment: Thanks, Torazaburo! Indeed -  this is a wise solution. fighting with FF though as it doesn't work in FF for some reason